# What should the GeometryField encoding be for a GeoJSON data source in an OGR VRT?

Tags: geojson, ogr, gdal-grid

I am trying to produce a color gradient for a temperature map and I am using gdal_grid, specifically:

```
gdal_grid -zfield "temperature" -a invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=0.0 -txe -72.5 -77.0 -tye 38.6 41.8 -outsize 400 400 -of GTiff -ot Float64 -l temperature map_layers.vrt temperature.tiff --config GDAL_NUM_THREADS ALL_CPUS
```

My .vrt:

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="temperature">
        <SrcDataSource>temperature/data/temperature.json</SrcDataSource>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint25D</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="longitude" y="latitude" z="temperature"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Originally I used a .csv as a data source (successfully) but I would like to use a GeoJSON file instead. I am not sure what to use for GeometryType and GeometryField (they are currently what I used for the .csv) and I haven't been able to find documentation or examples.

Here is a snippet of the GeoJSON:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [-74.660809, 41.322093]
},
"properties": {
"name": "High Point Monument",
"solarradiation1avg_5min": "",
"soiltemperature_50cm": "",
"pressure": "",
"watercontentvf_50cm": "",
"soiltemperature_5cm": "",
"watercontentvf_20cm": "",
"heatindex": "",
"relhumid": "",
"winddir": "343.5",
"windchill": "",
"watercontentvf_5cm": "",
"watercontentvf_10cm": "", 
"soiltemperature_20cm": "",
"windsp": "9.3",
"temperature": "57.1", 
"soiltemperature_10cm": "",
"windspmax_5min": "19.0",
"precipitation": "",
```

So the latitude and longitude are together as coordinates, whereas in the CSV they were separate columns.

Can you point me to the right documentation?

Comment: The CRS for GeoJSON is CRS:84

Comment: You can use GeoJSON directly as a source. No need to write VRT at all.